Keyboard Stops working ubuntu 24 LTS
I recently upgraded to ubuntu 24 LTS latest version and now the keyboard stops working.  I have a dual boot desktop, and a Microsoft ergonomic keyboard.  The keyboard hardware seems to work well in my other OS (Windows), so I don't think it is a hardware issue.  I recently applied all the updates I saw too.
After boot I have about 5 minutes of ability to type, then the keyboard stops.  Either it stops taking any input or it acts as if a key is held down.  In that case it repeats a key ad infinitum in the active window.  My only recourse is then to reboot and so gain another few minutes...
First I followed a post that a module breaks the keyboard here on Ask Ubuntu.  sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf
Add a line to the file, optionally with a comment explaining why you are doing this
bug in module breaks keyboard, so don't load it
blacklist intel_vbtn
Save the file, exit and reboot.  This did not work for me.
Next I followed a comment below  to use dmesg to diagnose.
The OS loaded is
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-010) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-23ubuntu4) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.42) #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 (Ubuntu 6.8.0-48.48-generic 6.8.12)
The usb keyboard  is recognized
[    1.695639] usb 5-1.3: Product: Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard
[    1.695643] usb 5-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    1.695646] usb 5-1.3: SerialNumber: 601464714021
[    1.713936] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.750550] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.750557] usbhid: USB HID core driver
The keyboard works for from 170 to 500 seconds then I get this message

After that point keyboard no longer adds any input.
Now I tried your suggestion.  
You can see in the picture. The first time I ran the command the keyboard was working and the second time it was not.  The output is the same.   As you see below, the fault address is changing from run to run, and the reason stays the same.  Also now that I look the end by the USB connection looks frayed.  I think its a bad connection. It is probably a hardware problem.  I am going to get another keyboard and try again and see if that helps.

Is the keyboard connected via USB? Run sudo dmesg -w in a terminal window which will show kernel messages. Then see if any relevant messages pop up there when the keyboard stops working. Also you could do the same with a tail -f /var/log/syslog for system log messages.

First I tried blacklisting the keyboard following on earlier post.  Following that comment wrote sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf and wrote a file with the line.  "blacklist intel_vbtn".  That didn't work.

I think that the ...device [04:00.0]... indicates the hardware that is causing the issue so for a bit more information do lspci |grep 04:00.0 to find out. Then I would do a lspci -v to get more verbose output and update your question with the 04:00.0 line and all the lines under that. I don't know anything about the PTE Read access is not set or other messages there but you could do some more web search based on the error if you have not already.

ok: fault address was 0xfff7d000  now is0xfff9c000 fault reason same 06.

Replaced keyboard.  Still get this error on dmesg -w  799.754881] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[  799.754894] DMAR: [DMA Read NO_PASID] Request device [04:00.0] fault addr 0xfff9e000 [fault reason 0x06] PTE Read access is not set
[  799.755114] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 102
[  799.755121] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: WARNING: Host System Error
[  799.755122] DMAR: [DMA Read NO_PASID] Request device [04:00.0] fault addr 0xfff9e000 [fault reason 0x06] PTE Read access is not set
[ 1056.363348] usb 5-1: usbfs: usb_submit_urb returned -19
[ 1383.887821] usb 3-5: new low-spee

For now I think I have a solution or at least a work around.  I tried a new keyboard but had same symptom.  However, I was able to unplug in and replug it in, and the keyboard works.  I tried the same with the old keyboard and that also is working.  I am not sure what the origin of the problem is. It may be related to sleep of the computer. But disconnecting and reconnecting seems to get the keyboard working again.  I will update if there is a change

You could try kernel parameter intel_iommu=off see here for details: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.8/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html if you have a grub command startup I think there is an option where you can temporarily add kernel parameters to the current startup (to test before making any permanent change). I can't remember exactly but I am sure you can find details online.
